# GaussianBlurImage in haskell-opencv (Haskell binding to OpenCV-3.1)

Tags: opencv, haskell, image-processing

H!

I'm using [haskell-opencv](https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv) library. I don't know if another one is using it, or know something about it.

I was trying to use gaussianBlurImage, but there's an error that I can't recognize.

I have this:

```
cropped image = do 
     resized <- resizeImage image
     gaussianBlurred <- gaussianBlurImage ((M.unsafeCoerceMat . getImageFromEither) resized)
```

Where **resized** is an *Either CV.Exception (M.Mat shape channels depth)* And I get from here `((M.unsafeCoerceMat . getImageFromEither) resized)` a `Mat shape (S channels) (S depth)` as gaussianBlurImage function needs.

The I defined gaussianBlurImage so:

`gaussianBlurImage image = runExceptT $ CV.pureExcept $ CV.gaussianBlur (V2 13 13 :: V2 Int32) 0 0 image`

And for me, it looks fine. Similar as here: [blur](http://lumiguide.github.io/haskell-opencv/doc/OpenCV-ImgProc-ImgFiltering.html#v:blur). But I get this error:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘'True’ with actual type ‘Elem depth0
>   '[Word8, Word16, Float, Double]’

I noticed, that my gaussianBlurImage has this type:

```
gaussianBlurImage :: (M.Mat shape0 ('S channels0) ('S depth0)) -> Either CV.CvException (Either CV.CvException (M.Mat shape0 ('S channels0) ('S depth0)))
```

And I liked this one:

```
gaussianBlurImage :: (M.Mat shape0 ('S channels0) ('S depth0)) -> Either CV.CvException (M.Mat shape0 ('S channels0) ('S depth0))
```

Maybe it has something to do.

I tried it with medianBlur, blur and with gaussianBlur. I used a not resized image, and an image with three channels and another with 2 (color and gray), and I always get the same error. I'm wondering if the error is in `M.unsafeCoerceMat image`. And why `'True` as expected type? I don't have idea

Comment: Can you provide a minimum complete example?  The fragment you provided isn't anything someone can paste into a file and try to compile themselves.

Comment: Here's a gist: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Chuck-Aguilar/2a4a0506c2924c4d72134a45dc19935c)

I saw that the problem was with the type of "depth" and added this: `(depth `In` '[Word8, Word16, Float], channels `In` '[1, 3, 4]) =>`. However, it still not working. I get this error: ` Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Either CV.CvException’ Expected type: Either CV.CvException () Actual type: IO ()` And that's weird, 'cause I should be able to show the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[haskell-opencv](https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv) is an excellent library, but sometimes it's difficult to use because there are a lot of documentation, but difficult to understand, and there are no many examples.

There, every Blur function need a `(M.Mat shape ('S channels) ('S depth))` matrix, but the matrix are usually so: `(M.Mat shape channels depth)`, where `'S` tells it's static.

I use this function:

`M.coerceMat` to have such a Matrix.

```
coerceMAt :: (ToShapeDS (Proxy shapeOut), ToChannelsDS (Proxy 
    channelsOut), ToDepthDS (Proxy depthOut))    
    => Mat shapeIn channelsIn depthIn    
    -> CvExcept (Mat shapeOut channelsOut depthOut)
```

As it returns `CVExcept`, I use `exceptError :: CvExcept a -> a` to get just the image.

But the most important is the definition of the function. There was the problem in my code. 
`depth` cannot be ambiguous, that's why I wrote:

```
forall height0 width0 channels depth . ( depth `In` '[Word8, Word16, Float, Double] , channels `In` '[1, 3, 4]) => M.Mat ('S '[height0, width0]) ('S channels) ('S depth) -> IO (M.Mat ('S '[height0, width0]) ('S channels) ('S depth))
```

Here's a complete example. I get an image, resize it, blur it and show it.

Main:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import qualified OpenCV.Internal.Core.Types.Mat as M
import Control.Monad ( void )
import qualified OpenCV as CV
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main :: IO ()
main = do
    test <- controller
    CV.withWindow "test" $ \window -> do
        CV.imshow window test  
        void $ CV.waitKey 10000
```

Lib:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Lib
    ( controller
    ) where

import BlurImage
import ResizeImage
import Utils
import Control.Monad ( void )
import Data.Word
import qualified OpenCV.Internal.Core.Types.Mat as M
import qualified OpenCV as CV
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

controller :: IO (CV.Mat (CV.S '[CV.D, CV.D]) (CV.S 1) (CV.S Word8))
controller = do
    file <- B.readFile "path/to/image.jpg"
    img <- return $ CV.imdecode CV.ImreadGrayscale file
    resized_little_img <- resizeImage img --little image for making a blur in and find the receipt
    blurImage ((CV.exceptError $ M.coerceMat resized_little_img) :: M.Mat (CV.S '[ CV.D, CV.D]) (CV.S 1) (CV.S Word8))
```

ResizeImage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

module ResizeImage
    ( 
    resizeImage
    ) where

import Utils
import Control.Monad ( void )
import Control.Monad.Except
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Word
import Data.Proxy
import qualified OpenCV as CV
import Linear.V2
import OpenCV.TypeLevel
import qualified OpenCV.Internal.Core.Types.Mat as M
import qualified OpenCV.Core.Types.Size as S
import qualified OpenCV.ImgProc.GeometricImgTransform as GIT
import GHC.Int (Int32)

resizingImage :: (M.Mat (CV.S [CV.D, CV.D]) CV.D CV.D) -> CV.CvExcept (M.Mat (CV.S [CV.D, CV.D]) CV.D CV.D)
resizingImage image = GIT.resize (GIT.ResizeAbs $ S.toSize $ (getSize w h Nothing (Just 500))) CV.InterCubic image
    where
        [h, w] = getHandW image

resizeImage :: (M.Mat (S '[CV.D, CV.D]) CV.D CV.D) -> IO(M.Mat (CV.S [CV.D, CV.D]) CV.D CV.D)
resizeImage image = do        
    resized <- return $ resizingImage image
    return $ CV.exceptError $ resized
```

BlurImage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

module BlurImage
    ( 
    blurImage
    ) where

import Utils
import Control.Monad ( void )
import Control.Monad.Except
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Word
import Data.Proxy
import qualified OpenCV as CV
import Linear.V2
import OpenCV.TypeLevel
import qualified OpenCV.Internal.Core.Types.Mat as M
import qualified OpenCV.Core.Types.Size as S
import qualified OpenCV.ImgProc.GeometricImgTransform as GIT
import GHC.Int (Int32)


medianBlurImage :: (depth `In` '[Word8, Word16, Float], channels `In` '[1, 3, 4]) => (M.Mat shape ('S channels) ('S depth)) -> CV.CvExcept (M.Mat shape ('S channels) ('S depth)) 
medianBlurImage image = CV.medianBlur image 13 

gaussianBlurImage :: (depth `In` '[Word8, Word16, Float, Double], channels `In` '[1, 3, 4]) => (M.Mat shape ('S channels) ('S depth)) -> CV.CvExcept (M.Mat shape ('S channels) ('S depth)) 
gaussianBlurImage image = CV.gaussianBlur (V2 13 13 :: V2 Int32) 0 0 image

blurImage :: forall height0 width0 channels depth . ( depth `In` '[Word8, Word16, Float, Double] , channels `In` '[1, 3, 4]) => M.Mat ('S '[height0, width0]) ('S channels) ('S depth) -> IO (M.Mat ('S '[height0, width0]) ('S channels) ('S depth))
blurImage image = do
    gaussianBlurred   <- return $ gaussianBlurImage image     
    return $ CV.exceptError $ gaussianBlurred
```

And that's it. :) I hope it can help someone.

Comment: Quite difficult to read such long lines. Usually, the maximum line length is kept [below 80 chars](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md#line-length).